# Cannot deploy functions to firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

As said in the title, when I was deploying my functions, some of the functions failed with errors that look like the following:

```
Build failed: {"cacheStats": [{"status": "MISS", "hash": "083901f592ca8770578aa2725fb28aea8db1997e505ec0d1825e328934e5ab87", "type": "docker_layer_cache", "level": "global"}, {"status": "HIT", "hash": "083901f592ca8770578aa2725fb28aea8db1997e505ec0d1825e328934e5ab87", "type": "docker_layer_cache", "level": "project"}]}
```

I was able to deploy those failed functions in the past without any problems, and I didn't change the code at all. And the weirdest thing is, I tried to re-deploy the failed functions several times, they would eventually be deployed.

The firebase-tools, firebase-functions and firebase-admin packages are updated to the date. I've tried to revert my code version as well as google the error, but nothing helps. Could someone tell me what the error means and how to deal with it please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're having problems deploying functions with the Firebase CLI, contact Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Curious that they point not to post here and the google team sometimes invite to post this type of problem/questions on stacoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely cause is the [outage](https://status.cloud.google.com/) that started a few hours ago (January 7th. 2020), affecting several Cloud Function deployments with errors such as `Build failed` and `INVALID_ARGUMENT`. Engineering is aware and they're working on it. If you're unsure or wish to stay up to date on it, [contact support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact?visit_id=637140091775563839-1350076797&rd=1).

Comment: Just confirmed with a Firebase support rep. Thanks for your comment!